# Ansible: how to evaluate a template and put the evaluated template into another template?

Tags: templates, ansible

We've got a scenario whereby we have to fill-up the final template file with another templated file.

The concept reference information is held in a CSV file which got details of contact and escalation points

```
#csv
incident_type,support_team,support_email
server_down,linux_group,linux@sample.com
server_crash,vmware_group,vm@sample.com
```

This then has to populate a contacts_details template. The template for contact group is something like

```
#contacts_details.template.j2
|  Item | Value  |
|---|---|
| incident_type  | {{incident_type}}  |
| support_team  | {{support_team}}  |
| support_email  | {{support_email}}  |
```

and this template object then have to populate the main Playbook for Operations to call-out is

```
#callout.playbook.j2
some stuff already there

{{contacts_details}}
```

So the ultimate aim is for Ansible to populate

- the contains_details template
- fill the callout.playbook with the filled values in the {{contacts_details}}

I've done populating the template easily using the Ansible template module

```
- name: filltemplates contacts_details
  template:
    src: contacts_details.template.j2
    dest: contacts_details.template
    
- name: filltemplates callout
  template:
      src: callout.playbook.j2
      dest: callout.playbook
```

But it fails at "callout" as it can't replace `{{contacts_details}}`

Anyway I can ensure the 1st template iteration is persisted into the 2nd template replace?

Final outcome expected is for a  `server_down` type alert is:

```
#My Nice Playbook
some stuff already there

|  Item | Value  |
|---|---|
| incident_type  | server_down  |
| support_team  | linux_group |
| support_email  | linux@sample.com |
```

Comment: I would guess using the [template lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/plugins/lookup/template.html) akin to `- set_fact: contact_details: "{{ lookup("template", "contact_details.template.j2") }}"` will allow you to write it out to `contact_details.template` as well as make it available to `callout.playbook`

Comment: thanks for the tip. will try and let you know/mark as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done as below

```
---
- name: Read a template and Put into another template
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: "show templating results"
      set_fact:
        contact_details: "{{ lookup('template', './templates/04_contact_details.j2') }}"
      vars:
        name: "bob"
        email: "bob@bob.com"
        phone: "12345"

    - name: "Update final template"
      template:
          src: "./templates/04_main_callout.md.j2"
          dest: "/tmp/main_callout.md"
          mode: preserve
```

where the templates are

```
04_contact_details.j2
|  Key |  Value |
|---|---|
| name  | {{name}}  |
| email  | {{email}}  |
| phone  | {{phone}}  |
```

The main template is

```
04_main_callout.md.j2
# Sample markdown

## aim is to fill up contact details automatically from another template

{{contact_details}}
```